# Magento 2 - Add custom attribute in customer registration form

Tags: magento2, attributes, eav, register

I want to add a custom attribute in customer registration form. I write a module with the following InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace vendor\TestModule\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {

    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'client_idn', [
            'label' => 'Client IDN',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 40,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => true]
        );

        // add attribute to form
        /** @var  $attribute */
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'client_idn');
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create']);
        $attribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

}
```

In database, the records are successfully inserted. 
[image]
[image]

However, the custom attribute does not show up in the registration form.
[image]

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 10):

If your install data script successfully installed your custom attribute, now you just need to override addition information phtml file and set your custom attribute in that.

Create Vendor/TestModule/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional_info_customer_client_idn" template="Vendor_TestModule::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Create Vendor/TestModule/view/frontend/templates/additionalinfocustomer.phtml

```
<fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend>
    <p>
    <div class="field regulation">
        <label for="regulation" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Client IDN') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="client_idn" id="client_idn" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Client IDN') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:false}">
        </div>
    </div>
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Clear cache and review frontend customer account registration page.

Comment: Vendor/TestModule/view/layout/customer_account_create.xml should be Vendor/TestModule/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

Comment: Hello... what to do to assign the value to the `INPUT` of the custom attribute? The problem is| that if the page is reloaded because of an error, all fields are repopulated with what the user entered in the form, except the custom fields.

Answer (score 1):

**@Jonak's answer "the most voted" is correct, however you need to create the layout folder inside frontend folder just like that:**

from:

> Vendor/TestModule/view/layout/customer_account_create.xml

to:

> Vendor/TestModule/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

Answer (score 0):

It should be added in front-end or html level.

Assume you are using Luma theme

Go to customer registration form `root/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml` add below code

```
<div class="field required">
    <label for="client_idn" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Client Idn') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="client_idn" name="client_idn" id="client_idn" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getClientIdn()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('client_idn') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Remove the cache and check the visibility in front end.

Check whether the value is passing to customer registration controller or not.

**@Aaron Allen said in comment override the file by module. editing code in core files is not recommended.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Override the file with your module instead. Editing a core file is bad.

Comment: @ Aaron Allen Thanks, i forgot to mention, modified the answer.

Comment: @krishnaijjada, but why this? `<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>`

Comment: it renders data from session if it is already set.             $formData = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerFormData(true);

Comment: but data is not saving from frontend

Answer (score 0):

you can checkout an excellent tutorial link for creating custom attribute for Customer. This also contains video.
 Follow the steps. It works. 
http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-add-custom-eav-attribute-to-category-or-customer

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It happen because your entity in

```
$customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'client_idn');
```

is

> Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute

But saving form data exist only in

> Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute

(have a look at function `_afterSave`)

## This is not best practice, but solution:

```
        $attribute = $this->attributeFactory->create();
        $attribute->loadByCode($attributeArray['type'], $attributeArray['code']);
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $attributeForms);
        $attribute->save();
```

where AttributeFactory is: `Magento\Customer\Model\AttributeFactory;`

attribute forms are:

```
    $attributeForms = [
        'customer_account_create',
        'customer_address_edit',
        'customer_register_address'
    ];
```

attribute array:

```
    [
        'type' => 'customer_address',
        'code' => 'title',
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your install data script successfully installed your custom attribute, now you just need to override addition information phtml file and set your custom attribute in that.

Create vendor/TestModule/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_login">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">vendor_TestModule::register.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create vendor/TestModule/view/frontend/templates/register.phtml

```
<fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
    <div class="field client idn">
        <label for="client_idn" class="label">
            <span>
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */echo __('Client IDN') ?>
            </span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="client_idn" id="client_idn" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Client IDN') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Clear cache & review frontend customer account registration page...