# How to add a custom attributes from backend in registration page in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-attributes

How to add a custom attributes from backend in
registration page in magento 2

Refer Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

***Magento opensource version does not have the feature to add customer attribute from admin just like Product.***

If you want to add a custom attribute to registration form then you have to do coding or use any extension.

***You can follow below link for adding a custom attribute to the registration form.***

[Magento 2 - Add custom attribute in customer registration form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128178/magento-2-add-custom-attribute-in-customer-registration-form)

https://www.truecodex.com/course/magento-2/how-to-add-custom-field-in-magento-2-registration-form

http://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/how-to-add-a-customer-attribute-programmatically-and-display-it-on-customer-registration-form-in-magento-2/

Comment: how to add a customer attributes dynamically from backend in magento 2